# Trying to compile Python fails because of files' timestamps

Tags: python, git, makefile, compilation

I want to compile Python; I cloned the repository from Github:

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch=2.7 https://github.com/python/cpython.git
```

Configure works but building fails because Python is not found:

```
$ cd cpython
$ ./configure
...
$ make
/bin/mkdir -p Include
./Parser/asdl_c.py -h Include ./Parser/Python.asdl
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory
Makefile:718: recipe for target 'Include/Python-ast.h' failed
make: *** [Include/Python-ast.h] Error 127
```

This is because `Include/Python-ast.h` is newer than `Parser/asdl_c.py`, as told by `make --debug`:

```
...
Prerequisite 'Parser/Python.asdl' is newer than target 'Include/Python-ast.h'.
Prerequisite 'Parser/asdl.py' is newer than target 'Include/Python-ast.h'.
Prerequisite 'Parser/asdl_c.py' is newer than target 'Include/Python-ast.h'.
Must remake target 'Include/Python-ast.h'.
```

Indeed, the header was cloned a little bit after the Python script:

```
$ ls --full-time Include/Python-ast.h Parser/asdl_c.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 piwi piwi 21113 2016-09-08 15:22:32.984000000 +0200 Include/Python-ast.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 piwi piwi 41414 2016-09-08 15:22:33.248000000 +0200 Parser/asdl_c.py
```

Touching the header works around the problem in this specific case:

```
$ touch Include/Python-ast.h
$ make
... compiles ...
```

Is there an appropriate way to prevent this behavior?

Thanks,

Comment: There is usually a .PHONY target `all` as the first target in the makefile like `all : target1 target2`. `make` or `make all` will always remake target1 and target2.

Comment: Another try is `make -B` or `make --always-make`.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's known issue. Use `make touch` after checkout, then `make` should work.

See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b72e279bfa0eece094f652b9fc329200d5964ffa/Makefile.pre.in#L1504